# Javascript objects/closures

Tags: javascript, closures

Can a JS guru out there explain why this:

```
$$={}
(function(x){
    x.newModule = {
            func: function(){...}
    };
})($$);
$$.newModule.func()
```

is superior to this?

```
$$.newModule = {
    func: function() {...}
}
$$.newModule.func()
```

Comment: What do you mean with superior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extra function gives you an extra local scope that you might want to use (though it is not in your short example).

```
(function(x){
    var privateFunction = function() {};
    var privateCounter = 1;
    x.newModule = {
            func: function(){...}
    };
})($$);
```

Comment: Also, `x` only saves one character over `$$`, but a real-world example might have `x` and `myNamespace.mySubNamespace.someObject` so if you needed to reference the object repeatedly to add multiple methods and/or properties giving it a one-character alias makes the code neater and easier to read.

Comment: @nnnnnn: And the module author might be a different person than the module user, and with this "export"-like syntax, each gets to choose her own favorite names.

Answer (score 0):

In the first pattern you can have private methods and variables which are not possible in the second pattern. That is the reason the first pattern is superior.